# packages for sending post through a mail, facebook or twitter using meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I want to provide the user with the option to share the posts on my website using mail, facebook or twitter... similar to this(https://hasjob.co/view/bl0dl), Please let me know the available packages or other ways in meteor & meteorite for implementing this features.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript plugins like sharethis can still be used with Meteor.

However, a specific Meteor package that will give you what you want is: [social share](http://beta.atmospherejs.com/package/social-share)